# Using ALTER TABLE command in psql to add to a table

Tags: sql, function, triggers, psql, alter-table

I am trying to solve this extra credit problem for my homework. So we haven't learned about this yet, but I thought I would give it a try because extra credit is always good. I am trying to write an ALTER TABLE statement to add a column to a table. The full definition is here.

> Use the ALTER TABLE command to add a field to the table called  rank
>   that is of type smallint.  We’ll use this field to store a ranking of
>   the teams.  The team with the highest points value will be ranked
>   number 1; the team with the second highest  points value will be
>   ranked number 2;    etc. Write a PL/pgSQL function named update rank
>   that  updates the rank field to contain the   appropriate number for
>   all teams.  (There are both simple and complicated ways of doing this.
>   Think about how it can be done with very little code.)  Then, define a
>   trigger named tr update   rank that fires after an insert or  update
>   of any of the fields {wins, draws}. This trigger   should be executed
>   once per statement (not per row).

The table that I am using is

```
  Table "table.group_standings"
    Column |         Type          | Modifiers

    --------+-----------------------+-----------
   team   | character varying(25)| not null
   wins   | smallint | not null
   losses | smallint | not null
   draws  | smallint | not null
   points | smallint | not null

  Indexes:
   "group_standings_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (team)
  Check constraints:
   "group_standings_draws_check" CHECK (draws >= 0)
   "group_standings_losses_check" CHECK (losses >= 0)
   "group_standings_points_check" CHECK (points >= 0)
   "group_standings_wins_check" CHECK (wins >= 0)
```

heres my code

```
ALTER TABLE group_standings ADD COLUMN rank smallint;
```

I need help with writing the function to rank the teams

Comment: I am going to update as I work on it. Just thought I would post so you guys can see what I am doing

Comment: @sebas thanks for the edit, do you have any idea on how to write this function? Im trying to think of way but none have come to mind yet

Comment: Hint: the rank is the number of teams (`COUNT()`) with more (actually, NOT <=) points than the team being updated.